# Система оплаты для Интернет-магазина

Tags: интернет-магазин

Здравствуйте!
Задался такими вопросами:

Как организуется система оплаты заказов (товаров) для Интернет-магазина?

Какие предварительные действия надо совершить?

Как работает сам механизм, его структура и организация?

Как правильно реализовать, и что для этого необходимо?

В Инете конкретныx ответы не нашел, поэтому будьте добры подскажите.

Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос хороший мне тоже интресен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Многое зависит от платежной системы, которую вы собираетесь использовать. С отечественными я не работал, но вот работа с такими системами как: PayPal, E-Bay, UsaEpay, Authorize.NET и некоторыми другими сводится обычно к бональному использованию их АПИ. Обычно у данных систем есть некие веб-сервисы (с документацией на сайте естественно) и вам нужно всего лишь научиться с ними работать. Более того, некоторые системы даже предоставляют "обёртку" в виде написанных ними библиотек под разные ЯП для работы со своим АПИ, что делает процесс еще более простым. Данное АПИ позволяет логиниться к ним в систему, проводить платежи на определенные кошельки, анализировать ошибки и другие транзакции с платежами. Качество данных АПИ бывает самым разным и иногда лучше использовать свой код, чем пользоваться ихним, ну да такое я встревал всего лишь раз. Важным моментом является при выборе подобной системы (если у вас конечно есть такая возможность) - это наличие тестового сервера на их стороне для проверки вашего кода на тестовых данных без реальных транзакций с деньгами! Это может быть большой проблемой, если вы сможете обнаружить ошибки только на этапе выхода в жизнь! Вкратце как-то так. Ну и для примера даже скажу некоторые цифры: для изучения любой платежной системы необходимо 2-3 дня максимум (если вам нужно банальный эл-магазин реализовать) и пару дней на внедрение в проект. Бывают конечно исключения, но обычно так выходит +-

Comment: А работали конкретно с PayPal? Как правильно создать кнопку для покупки? Какие поля за что отвечают в форме кнопки? Не могу понять как интегрировать в сайт все это...

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: http://www.phpclub.ru/detail/article/paypal#ipn - думаю найдете ответ, так как если все писать нужно много времени и сил :)

Answer (score 0):

[система приема платежей](http://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest). Информации масса, как подключить, пользоваться и т.д. Нужно только почитать!

Comment: Абсолютно согласен насчет информации! Вопрос висит давно и я только поэтому и не отвечал на него =)

Answer (score 0):

[ROBOKASSA](http://robokassa.ru/ru/) вот с этим зверьком работаю я.
У них все просто в исполнении, нужно всего несколько скриптов для проверки и отправки данных на оплату. Работает сервис без нареканий. У них есть тестовый период когда ты можешь тестить свои скрипты и проверять входные и выходные данные, тем самым обеспечить безошибочную работу при старте системы.